# C# UIElement LostTouchCapture OnLostTouchCapture

Tags: c#, capture, pixelsense, uielement

I am building an application for the Samsung SUR40 in MS Surface 2.0.

I cant let the `LostTouchCapture` work anymore.

This is my XAML code:

```
<Rectangle 
   x:Name="ActiveArea" 
   Fill="Transparent" 
   TouchDown="OnTouchDown" 
   TouchMove="OnTouchMove" 
   LostTouchCapture="OnLostTouchCapture" 
/>
```

A piece of my C# code:

```
private void OnLostTouchCapture(object sender, TouchEventArgs args)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
}
```

The TouchDown and TouchMove do work. But I have a problem with the `LostTouchCapture`.
The function was working but now its broke and I dont know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't fix it really, but I use the `TouchLeave="OnTouchLeave"` instead.

Comment: I don't think this is the best solution, since it's constantly firing, but it seems to be the only one that works so far. I noticed that if you remove the `TouchDown` event, the `TouchUp` is fired (you should always add the `IsManipulationEnable = true` to the desired UI element), but if you put both, the `TouchUp` stops being fired. Maybe it has to do with handling the `TouchDown` event, however I already marked it as `false` and still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You were using the wrong event anyways, if you want to get the event when the touch leaves the rectangle, `TouchLeave` is the event you are looking for, `LostTouchCapture` event is when you are tracking the `TouchDevice` on an `UIElement` (for `DragDrop` or `Manipulation`) using `Capture` on the `TouchDevice`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.uielement.loststyluscapture.aspx instead, it worked for me.